# XSLT XML to HTML - modifying/copying elements

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<main>
    <sect1>
        <line>Some text<sub value="4">Sub number 4.</sub>. And some more text<sub value="5">Sub number five.</sub>.</line>
        <line>Yet more text<sub value="6">Sub number 6.</sub>.</line>
    </sect1>
    <sect1>
        <line>Would you believe yet more text<sub value="8">Eighth sub.</sub>.</line>
        <line>Incredible, there's more<sub value="9">Good ol' sub number 9.</sub>.</line>
    </sect1>
</main>
```

I want to use XSLT to convert that to the following HTML (with some additional tag name changes that aren't relevant to this query):

```
<main>
    <sect1>
        <line>Some text<num>4</num>. And some more text<num>5</num>.</line>
        <line>Yet more text<num>6</num>.</line>
        <sub>4 Sub number 4.</sub>
        <sub>5 Sub number five.</sub>
        <sub>6 Sub number 6.</sub>
    </sect1>
    <sect1>
        <line>Would you believe yet more text<num>8</num>.</line>
        <line>Incredible, there's more<num>9</num>.</line>
        <sub>8 Eighth sub.</sub>
        <sub>9 Good ol' sub number 9.</sub>
    </sect1>
</main>
```

So, the sub elements nested in each line should (1) change to a num element and contain only the value attribute as text; (2) also appear after all of the line elements in each sect1, in the concatenated form: value, [space], text.

I can get the sub to transform thus:

```
<xsl:template match="sub">
    <sub>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@value, ' ', "." />
    </sub>
</xsl:template>
```

but I don't know how to change sub to num as described (I can manage to delete it completely), or how to copy all of the subs to after the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `<sub>` must be processed twice:

- When first encountered, it is replaced with a `<num>`.
- At the end of each `<sect1>`, all nested `<sub>`s are repeated with their `value` attribute inserted before their content. This is done by the template in `mode="sub"`.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::sect1/descendant::sub" mode="sub" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="sub">
    <num>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
    </num>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="sub" mode="sub">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(XSLT 1.0)